# Is it possible to convert UTF32 text to UTF16 using only Windows API?

Tags: visual-c++, unicode

I'm trying to find converting UTF-32 text to/from any code page is possible using the Windows API alone. I cannot used CLR to do this task.

The Code page identifiers page at Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(VS.85).aspx lists UTF-32 as being available to only managed applicatiosn.

ConvertStringTo/FromUnicode fails when UTF-32 is used.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function that takes the UTF-32 codepoint to be converted to it's equivalent UTF-16 codepoint (single or surrogate as the case may be) as the first argument and the high and low surrogates as second and third arguments.
The high and low surrogate values are returned by reference.

If the codepoint is below 0x10000, then we simply return that codepoint in the low surrogate by reference while the high surrogate is 0.

If the codepoint is greater than 0x10000, then, we calculate the high and low surrogate pairs using the rules given on this wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_UTF-16_encoding_procedure

Here's the code:

```
unsigned int convertUTF32ToUTF16(unsigned int cUTF32, unsigned int &h, unsigned int &l)
{
    if (cUTF32 < 0x10000)
    {
        h = 0;
        l = cUTF32;
        return cUTF32;
    }
    unsigned int t = cUTF32 - 0x10000;
    h = (((t<<12)>>22) + 0xD800);
    l = (((t<<22)>>22) + 0xDC00);
    unsigned int ret = ((h<<16) | ( l & 0x0000FFFF));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The code no longer exists here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_UTF-16_encoding_procedure

I looked at Wiki around the time you posted this answer.  The code did not exist.  Do you have a date when this code existed?  I want to update to use an archive.org link.  Thank you!

Comment: @kevinarpe I didn't mean the code in the Wikipedia link in my answer. I meant that the "rules' based on which I posted the code could be seen on that link.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of knowledge of Unicode you should be able to create a UTF32 to UTF16 converter without using any APIs.

All characters in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF can simply have the upper 16 bits removed.

Values in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF can be converted into two 16-bit words, called surrogate pairs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Encoding_of_characters_outside_the_BMP

Comment: The answer is that it you cannot use Window API for this. You need to do it yourself.
Here is a link to a tested code for this, from unicode: http://www.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/CVTUTF/

Comment: They have now referred this on to [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) in their FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iconv library in Windows.  It fully supports UTF-32 (big and little endian).

Comment: I don't want to use any external library for this. An alternative library is libICU

Comment: This you will have to write your own code to convert between UTF-16 and UTF-32.  It is not difficult to do manually.